# How to inform other processes that a file has marked for deletion?

Tags: c++, c, linux

I am currently writing a **C** application for an embedded system (limited disc space)
On this system, several processes access files which I have to delete with my application on certain events (e.g. **running out of disc space**). But since the other processes still can write to these files, the disc space situation doesn't improve.

**Is there any possibility to actually delete the file and let the write access of the other processes fail?**

I have only limited access to the behavior of the other processes so it would be nice if no cooperation of these processes is needed.

Comment: How hacky may the solution be? I can imagine something with ptracing those processes and closing the fds of those files...

Comment: @PlasmaHH lets say it this way: I would prefer a nice short and simple solution, but the files have to go and if these nifty little processes don't want to give up control over the files, I have to force them.

Comment: @Joze Protecting the file won't work, because that would need a large amount of cooperation of the other processes on linux systems and I can't know if i get this.

Comment: Can you restart those processes?

Comment: Other Unix-like systems have a system call for this called `revoke`. Unfortunately it doesn't seem that Linux can do this (the stub in glibc only returns `ENOSYS`).

Comment: @cha0site I am not entirely sure if I will be able. At least i don't know who these processes will be. Also i don't know if any of this processes is really important. You don't want to switch of something really important for a few seconds just because you are running out of log space.

Comment: @Andreas: You can figure out which processes have files open with `fuser` or `lsof`. And you're right about restarting them, which is why I was asking... A lot of daemons close all open files when you send them a `SIGHUP`, but that might not be the case for your programs.

Comment: Check if `setfacl` is available on your system. http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl

Comment: @Andreas: then do you know how these processes would react to writes unexpectedly failing?

Comment: @Michał Actually I don't know, but they would run out of disc space and fail anyway so making them fail and hope they try to reopen the file is better then letting them fill the disk and hope for the best.

Answer (score 4):

Two ideas come to mind to go around the fact that the file doesn't actually get deleted until all references to it are closed:

1. if possible or permitted in your situation, unlink those files and then restart the other processes.
2. truncate/empty those files without deleting them.

Comment: Truncation is the solution. +1

Comment: Thanks for your answer the truncate looked great on the first view, processes can still write without problems to their open files, but since the filepointer doesn't get changed, the other processes seem to continue writing where they stopped. Which results in a file not smaller than before but with leading zeros.

Answer (score -1):

If I was the owner of the "other processes", I would just let them close, rename and reopen the log files, as soon as their size reach a given threshold. In this way the log rotation can be performed in a "standard" way (eg: [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate))

However it seems that you already have some *legacy* applications.

In this case I would suggest to use [mkfifo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo) to create named pipes in place of the log files, before the *legacy* applications are started.

Your **C** application will read from those special files, and in this way it will be able for example to create log files no longer than a specified amount. In this way you will be able to use **logrotate**, for example.

Drawback: if your **C** application is not running, the *legacy* applications will stay stuck in the `write()` system call, trying to write to a *non-connected* pipe.